# How Do I Unit Test A Jersey REST API Without Running A Server?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, testng

I am working with a REST API that is using Jersey with Spring Boot (so no specific application context in XML or Java) and Spring Data JPA.

I want to write unit tests on the GET and POST endpoints, however, I don't want to start a web server as it takes too long.

If I use `JerseyTest` my Spring Beans don't get loaded into the context.

```java
public class InMemoryContainerPackageTest extends 
        JerseyTestNg.ContainerPerClassTest {

  @Override
  protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new InMemoryTestContainerFactory();
  }

  @Override
  public Application configure() {
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
                              .register(SpringLifecycleListener.class)
                              .register(RequestContextFilter.class)
                              .register(this)
                              .register(MyController.class)
                              .packages("com.my.service");
    return config;
  }
```

If I use `SpringBootTest` it starts up a web server which takes about 30 seconds and ideally I want all my tests to complete in under 5 seconds otherwise developers won't run them.

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestNGClass1 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

I don't think `MockMvc` works with Jersey endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use `JerseyTest` my Spring Beans don't get loaded into the context.

What you can do is set the property `"contextConfig"` in your `ResourceConfig`. The value will be a Spring `ApplicationContext` instance. So if you are using Java configuration, you would just use an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

```java
@Override
public ResourceConfig configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig()
            .register(TestResource.class)
            .property("contextConfig",
                    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class));
}
```

Here, `SpringConfig` is an arbitrary Spring `@Configuration` class. Below is a complete example.

```java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;


public class SpringTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static class MessageService {
        public String getMessage() {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class SpringConfig {
        @Bean
        public MessageService service() {
            return new MessageService();
        }
    }

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @Autowired
        private MessageService service;

        @GET
        public String get() {
            return service.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .register(TestResource.class)
                .property("contextConfig",
                        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class));
    }

    @Override
    public TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new InMemoryTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        Response res = target("test")
                .request()
                .get();

        String msg = res.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(msg);
        assertThat(msg).isEqualTo("Hello World");
    }
}
```

As far as the JPA, you are going to have to configure that yourself. When using Spring Boot, all of the JPA bootstrapping is taken care of. If you are going to use Jersey Test Framework, then you are ignoring all Spring Boot configuration.

It's really not that hard to configure JPA yourself. It basically consists of configuring a `DataSource`, a `TransactionManager`, a `JpaVendorAdaptor`, and a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. And to enable the Spring Data repositories, you just need to use the `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Have a look at [this complete example configuration](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/underdog/jersey/spring/example/SpringConfig.java).

Another thing to be wary of is that when we use the Jersey Test Framework, we will not have the test scoped transactions (and rollbacks) that you will get when working with Spring Test. So when you write your tests, you need to take this into consideration.